# Rails Article.find 1 raises ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid on legacy database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, exception, activerecord

I'm creating a rails app over a legacy database table. Everything works fine locally, but on the server I hit this error whenever I do Article.find(1)

```
Could not log "sql.active_record" event. NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."" = $1 LIMIT 1
```

The legacy database has an id field, however the schema describes the id with

```
create_table "articles", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.decimal  "id", :precision => 10, :scale => 0, :null => false
  ...
```

Note that Article.find_by_id(1) returns the record without any problem.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**UPDATED** - See below

It turns out, adding the following to the model fixes this:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :id 
  ...
```

Presumably, because rails didn't create the table, it doesn't know what field the primary key is. It seems a little odd though, an educated guess with a warning - or even a more friendly error message - would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
Rails 3.2+ the above method is deprecated. The new method is as follows:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :id 
  ...
```

Thanks to @lboix for pointing this out!

Answer (score 4):

Seems that this option has been updated guys : [set_primary_key error in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386636/rails-set-primary-key-error)

Hope it will help :)

Take care