# set_primary_key error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, primary-key

I'm creating a table called `Index`. Here's the migration:

```
class CreateIndices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :indices, {:id => false} do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.float :returns, array: true, default: []
      t.float :navs, array: true, default: []
      t.float :sharpe

      t.timestamps
    end

    execute "ALTER TABLE indices ADD PRIMARY KEY (name);"
  end
end
```

That all works fine. I saw in another Stack Overflow question that I have to include the `set_primary_key` command in my model to get it to work, so I have the following in the index.rb

```
class Index < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :name

end
```

Besides these two files, I haven't changed anything from the default Rails scaffolding (the app was created with Postgres as the default database). When I go to `localhost:3000/indices`, I get the following error

```
undefined method `set_primary_key' for #<Class:0x37132e0>
```

If I comment out the `set_primary_key` line it loads the regular empty scaffold, but I assume this does not give me the primary key functionality that I want. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: apparently, putting "self.primary_key= :name" in the model works, but since I'm learning, I would still like to know why the standard syntax isn't working here

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're using rails 3.2 or higher, the `set_primary_key` method was depreciated, check out the [Rails 3.2 release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html) - Section 8.1 and it suggests using an assignment method instead like `self.primary_key=`, just like you said you did in your comment

Comment: Oh i see, I guess googling random answers without paying attention to the version is a flawed approach

Answer (score 0):

Exactly it's currently a class method :

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/PrimaryKey/ClassMethods.html#method-i-primary_key-3D

Don't forget the adequate migration :

```
def up

    create_table :books, {id: false, primary_key: :key_id} do |t|
      t.timestamps
      etc.
    end

    execute <<-SQL
        ALTER TABLE books
        ADD PRIMARY KEY (key_id)
    SQL

end

def down

    drop_table :books

end
```

If you want to use this new primary key in your generated routes (routes.rb) :

```
resources :books, only: [:show, :edit, :update], param: :key_id
```

Hope it helps !

Take care

Answer (score -2):

Weird. As per [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/set_primary_key/class) I would have expected

```
class Index < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_primary_key "name"
end
```

to work. The only difference I can see is `"name"` string vs your `:name` symbol which shouldn't make any difference.

**Update**

Actually, bang up the top of that link is a deprecated message (sorry). Apparently it's now a class method so that explains the need for `self.set_primary_key`. Doh!